# Problema con servicio de windows y Crystal reports Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, servicio, crystal-reports

Tengo una aplicación que guarda datos en una tabla en sql server y al finalizar se iteran las filas grabadas para genera un reporte de crystal, por cada fila, que se guardan como pdf en una carpeta de destino, todo ocurre en segundo plano sin que se entere el usuario ni aparezca el informe de Crystal reports en pantalla.

Esto funciona perfecto en la aplicación pero como necesito que el proceso sea automático creé un servicio de windows para realizar ésta tarea sin intervención del usuario. Transcribí la parte del codigo que hace la tarea pero cuando llega a la siguiente linea: `Dim reporte As New CrystalReport4` pasa a la clase Public class CrystalReport4 y en:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New      'Acá el error
End Sub
```

me da el siguiente error cuando trata de ejecutar MyBase.New :

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.'

Estoy muy perdido como para intentar una solución, hay muy poca información el la web. Traté, sin tener mucha idea de lo que estaba haciendo, de:
1- Enviar parámetros,
2- cambiar MyBase.New por MyClass.new con o sin parámetros,
3- actualizar el runttime de Crystal reports,
4- agregar en las referencias del proyecto *CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion*.

No se si tiene que ver con que los servicios de windows están hechos para correr en segundo plano sin interacción con el usuario y los reportes se muestran en pantalla pero por la forma en que tengo hecho el código el reporte solo genera el PDF sin mostrarlo en pantalla.

Adjunto el código:

Esto es lo que está en el service1.vb:

```
     Private Sub GuardaPDF()
            Dim mensaje As New MailMessage
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
            Dim reporte As New CrystalReport4
            Dim codFam As Integer
            Dim directorio As String = "C:\Vencimientos"
            Dim rutaVencimiento As String
    
            Try
                If Not Directory.Exists(directorio) Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(directorio)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
    
            Dim vencimiento As String = "SELECT codigo_familia
                                         FROM vencimiento_detallado 
                                         WHERE year(fecha_vencimiento) = " & Year(Date.Now) & " AND month(fecha_vencimiento) = " & Month(Date.Now) & "
                                         GROUP BY codigo_familia
                                         ORDER BY codigo_familia ASC"
            Dim adaptadorVencimiento As New SqlDataAdapter(vencimiento, conexion)
            Dim tablaVencimiento As New DataTable
    
            adaptadorVencimiento.Fill(tablaVencimiento)
            If tablaVencimiento.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                For Each fila As DataRow In tablaVencimiento.Rows()
                    codFam = fila("codigo_familia")
    
                    Dim rpt As String = "C:\Rpts\Clientes.rpt"
                    reporte.SetParameterValue("@codFam", codFam)
                    'CrvInforme.ReportSource = reporte
    
                    Dim mes As String = Month(Now).ToString
                    Dim anio As String = Year(Now).ToString
                    subCarpeta = mes & "-" & anio
    
                    If Not Directory.Exists(subCarpeta) Then
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\Vencimientos\ " & subCarpeta & " ")
                    End If
    
                    reporte.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "C:\Vencimientos\ " & subCarpeta & "\ " & codFam & ".pdf")
                    Dim ruta = "C:\Vencimientos\ " & subCarpeta & "\" & codFam & ".pdf"
                Next
    
                rutaVencimiento = "C:\Vencimientos\ " & subCarpeta
                Try
                    Dim rutaVenc As String = "INSERT INTO ruta_vencimiento(periodo_vencimiento, ruta, anulado) 
                                    VALUES(@periodo_vencimiento, @ruta, @anulado)"
                    Dim comandoRv As New SqlCommand(rutaVenc, conexion)
    
                    comandoRv.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periodo_vencimiento", fechaActual)
                    comandoRv.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruta", rutaVencimiento)
                    comandoRv.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anulado", "no")
                    comandoRv.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End If
        End Sub
```

Y este es el código en la clase del Crystal:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' <auto-generated>
    '     Este código fue generado por una herramienta.
    '     Versión de runtime:4.0.30319.42000
    '
    '     Los cambios en este archivo podrían causar un comportamiento incorrecto y se perderán si
    '     se vuelve a generar el código.
    ' </auto-generated>
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Option Strict Off
    Option Explicit On
    
    Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
    Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    
    
    Public Class CrystalReport4
        Inherits ReportClass
    
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New         ' Acá el error
        End Sub
    
        Public Overrides Property ResourceName() As String
            Get
                Return "CrystalReport4.rpt"
            End Get
            Set
                'Do nothing
            End Set
        End Property
        
        Public Overrides Property NewGenerator() As Boolean
            Get
                Return true
            End Get
            Set
                'Do nothing
            End Set
        End Property
```

El código sigue pero supongo que no es relevante.

A esta altura ya no se si estoy tratando de hacer algo que es imposible, como usar reportes en un servicio de windows,  o si hay forma de hacerlo. Estoy bastante perdido. Agradeceré cualquier aporte. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Revisa la versión de Net Framework de la aplicación donde si te funciona y la versión del servicio. Revisa la version de las librerias en ambos proyectos tambien.

Comment: Otra cosa a tener en cuenta (la cual me dio muchos problemas anteriormente) es en si estas compilando la aplicación para x64 o x86 bits, revisa eso tambien, deberia coincidir todo con la aplicación donde si te funciona.

Comment: Hola. El framework es el mismo :8.0  y la compilación también (Any CPU)pero no se como verificar la versión de las librerías.

Comment: En el mismo proyecto en el apartado Referencias te aparecen todas las librerias, si haces click encima de ellas y miras las propiedades te aparece la version y el path donde se aloja el archivo de la libreria (por si quieres mirar la version directamente al archivo)

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien en algo. El servicio no ejecuta lo que está en otro proyécto. yo lo que hice es copiar todo el codigo e insertarlo en un servicio. Todo el codigo que subí está en sel servicio de windows. Por eso pienso que el error se debe a que o no se pueden generar informes del crystal desde un servicio o hay que hacerlo de otra manera. Pensé que en una de esas sí funcionaba porque el reporte se genera sin mostrarlo al usuario y se guarda como pdf. Incluso creé un informe de crystal vacío y da el mismo error.